# How to connect Pagecounter to ScrollView

Tags: swift

Trying to connect my pagecounter to my scroll view, but for some reason it does not change when the image is scrolled.

Wrote code calculating the image size change in the scroll view.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageCounter: UIPageControl!

    var page = 0
    var myImages = [UIImage]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var posX: CGFloat = 0
        let scrollWidth = myScrollView.frame.size.width
        let scrollHeight = myScrollView.frame.size.height
        myScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        myImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "61763233_2273795276270684_2413481963462590464_o"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "64431295_2284501085200103_3314220009403711488_n"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hrc1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "66263822_2295361957447349_1103112725925462016_n"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "62022794_2274568069526738_785458383527346176_o")]
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        pageCounter.numberOfPages = myImages.count
        pageCounter.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        pageCounter.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blue

        for img in myImages {
            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight))
            imgView.image = img
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.clipsToBounds = true          
            myScrollView.addSubview(imgView)
            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth * CGFloat(myImages.count), height: scrollHeight)
            posX = posX + scrollWidth
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth = myScrollView.frame.size.width
        let getpage = round(myScrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
        let currentPage = Int(getpage)
        page = currentPage
        pageCounter.currentPage = page
    }
```

The page counter should change after every scroll.

Comment: rate my answer if was useful thx

Answer (score 0):

set your PageCounter Inside your ScrollView

example:

where ***pageCounter*** is your object and ***scrollView*** is your scrollView

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageCounter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 15),
            pageCounter.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
            pageCounter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            pageCounter.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ])
```

Answer (score 0):

"myScrollview.delegate = self"

this line of code was missing. Making it impossible to connect with the page control